# How to resolve Group and Sort withing XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have the following input message where the data needs to be grouped based on 'EmpNo' and 'Date' first. But the result should be taken from the latest date time from field 'lastDateTime'

Input XML:

```
<Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>3</Hours>
  <EmpNo>825</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-12T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>4</Hours>
  <EmpNo>826</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-12T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>5</Hours>
  <EmpNo>827</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-12T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>3</Hours>
  <EmpNo>825</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-14T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>4</Hours>
  <EmpNo>826</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-10T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>5</Hours>
  <EmpNo>827</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-12T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>3</Hours>
  <EmpNo>825</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-10T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>4</Hours>
  <EmpNo>826</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-11T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>5</Hours>
  <EmpNo>827</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-16T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1139</Rate>
  <Code>102486</Code>
</Record>
</Record>
```

There could be many EmpNo with different Dates as well in the Input XML file. This needs to be grouped but it requires to extract only that particular node where lastDateTime is the latest.

Expected Result:

```
<Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>6</Hours>
  <EmpNo>825</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-14T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1142</Rate>
  <Code>13</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>4</Hours>
  <EmpNo>826</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-12T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1140</Rate>
  <Code>11</Code>
</Record>
<Record>
  <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
  <Hours>11</Hours>
  <EmpNo>827</EmpNo>
  <lastDateTime>2019-04-16T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
  <Rate>1147</Rate>
  <Code>18</Code>
</Record>
</Record>
```

I tried to write the following code but no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="Record">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="EmpNo">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Date">
            <xsl:copy>
                <EmpNo>
                    <xsl:value-of select="EmpNo"/>
                </EmpNo>
                <Date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
                </Date>
                <lastDateTime>
                    <xsl:value-of select="max(current-group()/lastDateTime/xs:dateTime(.))"/>
                </lastDateTime>
                <Hours>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Hours[Date=max(current-group()/lastDateTime/xs:dateTime(.))]"/>
                </Hours>                
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Well, group with `xsl:for-each-group`, then inside process `current-group()` sorting on `lastDateTime` and output only the latest one.

Comment: tried to do that, facing problem in retrieving the other values. Code attached in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description I think you want

```
<xsl:template match="Record">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="EmpNo">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Date">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="xs:dateTime(lastDateTime)"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, result at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mB is

```
<Record>
   <Record>
      <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
      <Hours>3</Hours>
      <EmpNo>825</EmpNo>
      <lastDateTime>2019-04-14T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
      <Rate>1139</Rate>
      <Code>102486</Code>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
      <Hours>4</Hours>
      <EmpNo>826</EmpNo>
      <lastDateTime>2019-04-12T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
      <Rate>1139</Rate>
      <Code>102486</Code>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Date>2019-04-01T00:00:00.000</Date>
      <Hours>5</Hours>
      <EmpNo>827</EmpNo>
      <lastDateTime>2019-04-16T08:35:38.000</lastDateTime>
      <Rate>1139</Rate>
      <Code>102486</Code>
   </Record>
</Record>
```

I am not sure from which item in a group you want to take the not grouped child elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Martin. I want to take all the values from that particular "Record" where lastDateTime is the latest within that group.

Comment: This results onlt the max lastDateztime but not the other elements like Hours, rate etc based on the lastDateTime.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I have added a new question, could you please help?